# Initcap with some restrictions

Tags: regex, oracle, capitalization, regexp-replace

I want to capitalize the every initial letter of a full name, but with a exception: the prepositions should be lowercase.

The prepositions are: ["da", "de", "di", "do", "du", "das", "des", "dis", "dos", "dus"].

I have this code so far, but it's horrible and incomplete. It will be so huge if I do this way (putting all the exceptions I need).

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE
    (INITCAP ('ronald DAS silva'), '(D|d)a', 'da'),
    '(D|d)o', 'do'), '(D|d)e', 'de'),'(D|d)o', 'do'),'(D|d)u', 'du'));
```

I already tried to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`(with this regex -> `^(d|D)[a-zA-Z]{1,2}$`) inside the `INITCAP` function, but I didn't get success.

So, is there a way to do it easier?

### **EDIT:**

I have this at the moment:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REGEXP_REPLACE(INITCAP('ronald DAS silva'), '([d|D][[:alpha:]]{1,2})', LOWER('\1')));
```

It's almost working, but the `LOWER` function for some reason is not doing his work, why? If I put LOWER('A') it works.

### **Edit 2 - Additional tests:**

Every name that starts with the letter "d" will be transformed to lowercase, and it should not happen.

Then there are some cases:

- Daniel
- Deivid
- Dijkstra
- Donald
- Duoling

### **Full code**

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_name IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(100);
  v_names t_name := t_name('    Donald     dIs    siLvA',
                           'daniEl    da sIlvA XaVIeR   ',
                           '   DeYse De Olivier dA     loPeS');
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('Name w/o format', 60, ' ') ||
                            'Name formatted');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('---------------------', 60, ' ') ||
                            '---------------------');

  FOR i IN 1..v_names.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(v_names(i), 60, ' ') ||
                          f_format(v_names(i)));
  END LOOP;
END;

FUNCTION f_format(p_str VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           INITCAP(p_str),
         '((D)([aeiou](s|$)?))', 'd\3'),
       '[[:space:]]+', ' ');       
END;
```

Comment: Why are using a pattern that looks for e.g. `da`, when that is already the case you want? Does [NLS_INITCAP'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions110.htm#SQLRF00676) give the result you want without needing further manipulation (if you specify the appropriate language)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've set `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=BRAZIL;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=PORTUGUESE;`, but it still didn't lowercase the prepositions.

Comment: How do you know the middle word is not a middle name instead of part of the last name?  I'm assuming in this language you could still have middle names AND one-word last names?  Could you have names from other nationalities with different rules?  This looks to be PL/SQL.  You may need to just make a function called format_name where you pass the name, apply your rules for determining the name components, apply your capitalizations, then return the formatted name.  May be easier in the long run then coming up with a complex regex.

Comment: Well, for now I just want  to exclude that prepositions and in the middle of the full name. And I thought I could do this using regex capture groups then replace to `LOWER()` that captured group. But I don't know how to do it in `Oracle`. Something like REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(INITCAP(**word**, **regex**, LOWER(**captured_group**)))); Did you understand?

Comment: I added it in question, can you take a look?

Comment: You are passing the string '\1' to LOWER()

Comment: Yes, how can I pass it as back reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it.  Initcap the whole string, then look for your pattern surrounded by spaces (remembered group 1).  Within that, break it apart so group 2 is the leading capital 'D', group 3 is the rest including the optional 's'.  Replace with a space, lowercase 'd', remembered group 3 and another space.  I would have to advise against using this in production though, as it is way too specific to this format of a name.

```
SQL> declare
     name varchar2(20) := 'ronald dis silva';
   begin
     dbms_output.put_line(
       REGEXP_REPLACE(INITCAP(name), '( (D)([aeiou](s|$)?) )', ' d\3 '));
   end;
   /
Ronald dis Silva

SQL>
```

A name starting with a 'd' works for me:

```
SQL> declare
  2       name varchar2(20) := 'donald dis silva';
  3     begin
  4       dbms_output.put_line(
  5         REGEXP_REPLACE(INITCAP(name), '( (D)([aeiou](s|$)?) )', ' d\3 '));
  6     end;
  7  /
Donald dis Silva
```

Example with some more complex names using a WITH clause to make it easier to plug in different names for testing:

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
      select '    Donald     dIs    siLvA'      from dual union
      select 'daniEl    da sIlvA XaVIeR   '     from dual union
      select '   DeYse De Olivier dA     loPeS' from dual
    )
    select REGEXP_REPLACE(INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE(trim(name), '\s+', ' ')), '( (D)([aeiou](s|$)?) )', ' d\3 ') newname
    from tbl;

NEWNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Donald dis Silva
Deyse de Olivier da Lopes
Daniel da Silva Xavier

SQL>
```

Comment: It was an interesting one.  Be careful if you use it in production as it will only work if the names are in this very format!

Comment: Yes, I will. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Hey @Gary_W, unfortunately I found a problem, inputs that starts with D like: Daniel Mark, Deivid are automatically passed to lowercase, in other words it isn't looking only for characters with 2~3 letters (exactly). Can you help me?

Comment: This is a good lesson in why specs are important before any work is done.  Please add some additional test names to your original post, along with expected output. I was concerned this solution would not be flexible but that is what you wanted.

Comment: Give the full name

Comment: Are you sure? I tested here with this `'donald dis silva'` and doesn't work.

Comment: See my edit above, worked fine for me.  Check for a typo in your regex. Tip: instead of saying "doesn't work" post exact code and it's output so we can copy and paste it to test.  Contrary to what my wife thinks, I'm not a mind reader!  :-)

Comment: @developer033 You had left out spaces in the regex.  See new example. Full examples of names and expected output would have eliminated some of this back and forth.  Good example of the need for good specifications before you start work!  Also I am not familiar with your language to know if the output is what you expect, you didn't say what it should be.

Comment: Well, for me, the spaces HERE wasn't doing any effect. With or without it wasn't working for that cases. The expected outputs are already on question, my friend, **ONLY** prepositions (that I wrote) should be lowercase, all the rest should be capitalized. That's why I didn't provide any extra outputs, because I wrote it before. Anyway, I will test it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107586/discussion-between-developer033-and-gary-w).